# How to control timestamp schema in pandas.to_parquet

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I noticed that column type for `timestamp` in the parquet file generated by `pandas.to_parquet` can be different depending on the version of pandas, e.g.

```py
In [1]: pd.__version__                                                                                                 
Out[1]: '1.0.5'


In [2]: pd.DataFrame([pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01')], columns=['a']).to_parquet('/tmp/test.parquet')                      

In [3]: !parquet-tools schema /tmp/test.parquet                                                                        
message schema {
  optional int64 a (TIMESTAMP_MILLIS);
}

In [4]: !parquet-tools head /tmp/test.parquet                                                                          
a = 1577836800000
```

```py
In [1]: pd.__version__
Out[1]: '1.1.2'

In [2]: pd.DataFrame([pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01')], columns=['a']).to_parquet('/tmp/test.parquet')

In [3]: !parquet-tools schema /tmp/test.parquet
message schema {
  optional int64 a (TIMESTAMP_MICROS);
}

In [4]: !parquet-tools head /tmp/test.parquet                                                                          
a = 1577836800000000
```

As seen above, `pandas-1.0.5` converts the type of timestamp to be `TIMESTAMP_MILLIS` while `pandas-1.1.2` converts it to be `TIMESTAMP_MICROS`.

I'm using `pandas-1.1.2`, but I need the type to be `TIMESTAMP_MILLIS` for downstream consumption of the parquet file (queried by [Presto](https://prestosql.io/)), how can do that, please?

I'm using the [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html) engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is configurable with `pyarrow`, luckily `pd.to_parquet` sends any unknown kwrgs to the parquet library.
looking at [pyarrow docs for ParquetWriter](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter.html) we find

> coerce_timestamps (str, default None) – Cast timestamps a particular resolution. The defaults depends on version. For version='1.0' (the default), nanoseconds will be cast to microseconds (‘us’), and seconds to milliseconds (‘ms’) by default. For version='2.0', the original resolution is preserved and no casting is done by default. The casting might result in loss of data, in which case allow_truncated_timestamps=True can be used to suppress the raised exception. Valid values: {None, ‘ms’, ‘us’}

so that means you can force the timestamp to milliseconds with

```py
df.to_parquet(path, coerce_timestamps="ms")
```

or to microseconds

```py
df.to_parquet(path, coerce_timestamps="us")
```

which makes this the code that you need

```
pd.DataFrame([pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01')], columns=['a']).to_parquet('/tmp/test.parquet', coerce_timestamps="ms")
```

Take note of this part of the docs too

> `allow_truncated_timestamps=True` can be used to suppress the raised exception.